# How can I sort array days of week by specific day in c#?

Tags: c#, sorting, dayofweek, days

sort array days by specific day in c#
I have 3 days {sunday, tuesday, friday}
I want to sort my array with monday and my array become { tuesday, friday , sunday}

Comment: Could you provide an *example* of the data and desired outcome, please?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to sort `array` from `Monday` to `Sunday` order:

```
Mon < Tue < ... < Sat < Sun
```

You can do it with a help of [DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=net-6.0) property, e.g.

```
DateTime[] array = new DateTime[] {
  new DateTime(2022, 2,  6), // Sun
  new DateTime(2022, 2,  8), // Tue
  new DateTime(2022, 2, 11), // Fri
};

Array.Sort(array, (left, right) => 
  (((int)(left.DayOfWeek) + 6) % 7).CompareTo(((int)(right.DayOfWeek) + 6) % 7));
```

Let's have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array
  .Select(d => $"{d:dd MMMM yyyy (ddd)}")));
```

Outcome:

```
08 February 2022 (Tue)
11 February 2022 (Fri)
06 February 2022 (Sun)
```